# Android application doesn't appear on recent apps list

Tags: android, mobile

i'm deploying an android application (Android 4.0.3) and when I press the home screen the application doesn't stay on the recent apps list. I've noticed that when I restart the application, it starts on the last screen i've navigated before press the home button. Anyone can help? Here is me Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/logo_home"
        android:allowBackup="true">
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.activity.CommunicatorActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:label="" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.test.activity.InputActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.test.activity.SettingsActivity" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.test.activity.OutputActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: It takes some time for the application to go into the recent apps list... are you positive you checked it again a few seconds after?

Answer (score 10):

I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that this is your problem:

```
android:label=""
```

In your root activity `CommunicatorActivity` you've set the label to be an empty string. This label is used to identify your app in the list of available apps and because it is empty, this may be causing it not to show up in the list of recent apps.

Comment: This answer solving problem.. It should be marked as result answer!!

Answer (score 5):

Remove **android:excludeFromRecents="true"** from your manifest

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
android:label="your app_name"
```

Answer (score 2):

## 2 things

Ok, there isn't something obvious in your manifest that should prevent it from appearing in your recents list.

### 1. Wrong identification

It's not always straight forward to tell which task contains your activity, using the GUI.
One of the possibilities is that an activity from some other app is on top of your task making you believe that your activity isn't there. Since, clearly it resumes to the last screen.

***I suggest you to remove the single top temporarily and check the same.***

### 2. Launcher modification

Has the launcher you use the standard launcher? Has the launcher or some other app modified the presentation or behavior of the recents screen (unlikely but worth a check)

***For this, I suggest using a stock launcher or try the same app on a different phone or an emulator.***

> What would help is steps you followed and some screen shots of recents
>   screen and also of your app

Comment: I've tested on other devices, but the problem is the same :/

Comment: @user1517951 would you post screen shots of each step you do. There must be something obvious you might be missing.

Comment: OP isn't using `launchMode="singleTask"`, he is using `launchMode="singleTop"`.

Comment: @DavidWasser It seems I understood singleTop but wrote singleTask, nice catch, updated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

The reason is that I had set android:label="" in manifest.xml.

I hadn't set android:launchMode="singleTop".

I declared on purpose android:label="" because I didn't find any better way to remove the title of the action bar from my main activity.

I turned android:label="app_name" again and everything now is OK; the app appears again in recent app list when pressing the home screen and doesn't start on the last navigated screen when restarting it.