# Exclude current activity from Recent Tasks

Tags: android, android-activity

My app, running in background, at some point displays activity to purposefully interrupt user's flow. My activity starts a new task, which **appears in "Recent Tasks" lists while being in foreground**. Is there any way it could be prevented? Setting `android:excludeFromRecents` does not work - activity is not presented anymore in "Recent Tasks" only after is has been paused.

Manifest looks like:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.recenttasks.MainActivity"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true">
</activity>
```

and activity is started this way:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The key thing you mentioned is

> appears in "Recent Tasks" lists while being in foreground

I think you can't change that behavior. I just tested on my app and the same thing happens. If I press the "recent tasks" button while having my activity in the foreground, it appears listed there. The moment I move out of it to another activity or to my phone's main screen, the activity is not listed anymore.

I also tested this on the built-in DeskClock app that comes with recent Android versions and the same behavior is present there when a new alarm is triggered. Note that the `AlarmAlertFullscreen` activity of that app has the same parameters you mentioned in your question.

I'm not sure you can circumvent this or why you would need to in the first place since the activity is not listed anymore once it loses the focus.

Comment: I am trying to emulate behavior of UsbDebuggingActivity, which pops up on 4.x devices when you connect it first time via adb. It seems that activity destroys itself when "Recent Apps" is popped up (even though I cannot see it from code so far http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2_r1/com/android/systemui/usb/UsbDebuggingActivity.java/#UsbDebuggingActivity)

Comment: OK, it uses `finishOnCloseSystemDialogs=true` in manifest. I should probably do the same.

Comment: Reporting in. Having finishOnCloseSystemDialogs did not help much - after tapping on "Recent Tasks" activity does not disappear, unlike UsbDebuggingActivity from android internals. I've decided not to spend much time on it and solved my initial problem by other means, so I dont have to exclude anything from Recent Tasks.

Comment: @RicardoLage, `+100` from me, since nobody else came with better answe However... do you have some update in regards to this topic? Since 2013, when you wrote this answer, did you find out some other interesting information related to this question? Please share your experience. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you are defined it in manifest that is enough but it is not coming..

ok..try add this flag also to your `Intnet` and start the Activity..

```
intnet.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
```

Answer (score 2):

*Should the user be able to return to it? (Meaning if it shows and user clicks recents, have they lost their chance to see the hidden activity or should it still be there?)*

**If they cannot return** to it anyway then the best action would be to `finish()` the activity `onPause()`. This will mean that as long as you have used `android:excludeFromRecents` and `android:noHistory="true"`, there will be no item in recents.

**If however you do wish to return** to the 'interruption' activity (but do not want a recents entry) you could consider still finishing the activity `onPause` - but also recording a `preference` flag (something like `IS_INTERSTITIAL`). Your *other* activities can then check this preference in `onResume` and, if it is `true`, send an `Intent` to restart the Interstitial instead - To the user it will just appear they are resuming the app in the same state as they left it (interstitial)

**Edit:** If the screen needs to stay (rather than be re-instantiated) it may be possible to use a [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html), although then you must worry about configuration changes. There is one hack you could try (explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16548916/984830)) -

**Set your label empty** By using `android:label=""` your recent task is excluded. however this is a definite hack which may produce inconsistent results (as I haven't tested it to be sure)

Comment: Finishing activity is not an option. Activity needs to stay alive.

Comment: If it really needs to stay alive (vs recreate) then my only suggestion is trying to explicitly set an empty label. I'm not sure if this hack still works on all devices for recent versions, so some testing would be advised

Comment: It's not noise. The label fix has been proven to work, has not been suggested here and was not marked in the question as something tried. It is *your* project which is broken so it's on you to test on more devices to decide if it fits your situation.

Comment: I have tested `android:label=""` as well as `android:label="@null"`. None of them makes any change.

Comment: Using android:label="" with android:excludeFromRecents="true" worked for the Fire TV, thanks for the tip!